# Randomizing Images using javascript #2

Tags: javascript, html

ok im trying to randomize the images on this code without editing the html code (only javascript can be edited) but its not working and the output is empty! also if i put randomImg() after div splash it works but shows the alt=random images on the output instead picture. how do i get it working without editing html and omit alt attribute of the image?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>HTML</title>
    <meta name="author" content="randomimg" />
    <!-- Date: 2014-03-06 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function randomImg()
      {
        var images = new Array();
        images[0] = "img06.jpg";
        images[1] = "img07.jpg";
        images[2] = "img08.jpg";
        images[3] = "img09.jpg";
        images[4] = "img10.jpg";
        var random = Math.ceil(Math.random()* images.length);
        if (random == 0) {random =1;
      }
      document.getElementById('splash').firstElementChild.src =images[random];}
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
       <h1><a href="#">Welcome</a></h1>
       <h2>Flower of the day</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="splash"><img src="virus.jpg" alt="random images"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A few issues: `images[]` doesn't exist outside of `randomImg()`. You're missing index 2 and 3 from `images[]` and you're never showing index 0 as you change it to 1. `Array` is zero-based so delete that line. Its possibly not showing because it picks 2 and 3 at random so doesn't have an image to display.

Comment: can you type the codes for me please? and yeah thanks for pointing that missing bit out :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would make an edit like that, but it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues: `images[]` doesn't exist outside of `randomImg()`. You're missing index 2 and 3 from `images[]` and you're never showing index 0 as you change it to 1. Array is zero-based so delete that line. Its not showing because it picks 2 and 3 at random so doesn't have an image to display.

You're code show be: **[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7KZ2F/)**

```
    function randomImg() {
    var images = new Array();
    images[0] = "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+0";
    images[1] = "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+1";
    images[2] = "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+2";
    images[3] = "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+3";
    images[4] = "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+4";

    /* 
    The length property of an array is one-based, whereas array
    indexes are zero-based so minus 1 is used to prevent it returning
    one over the upper index of the array.
    e.g. images.length returns 5 but the upper index is 4.
    */
    var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * images.length-1);

    document.getElementById('splash').firstElementChild.src = images[random];
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', randomImg);
```

---

#### Updated code with alt updating

If you also want to update the `alt` attribute you'll need to store that in the `images` array and update it like you were with `src`.

**[Fiddle demo with alt updating](http://jsfiddle.net/7KZ2F/1/)**

```
function randomImg() {
    var images = new Array();
    images[0] = {
        src: "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+0",
        alt: "image 0"
    },
    images[1] = {
        src: "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+1",
        alt: "image 1"
    },
    images[2] = {
        src: "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+2",
        alt: "image 2"
    },
    images[3] = {
        src: "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+3",
        alt: "image 3"
    },
    images[4] = {
        src: "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=image+4",
        alt: "image 4"
    };
    /* 
    The length property of an array is one-based, whereas array
    indexes are zero-based so minus 1 is used to prevent it returning
    one over the upper index of the array.
    e.g. images.length returns 5 but the upper index is 4.
    */
    var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * images.length - 1);

    var imgElem = document.getElementById('splash').firstElementChild;

    imgElem.src = images[random].src;
    imgElem.alt = images[random].alt;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', randomImg);
```

Comment: yep! brilliant works!! thanks alot sir!! but it still shows random images (alt=random images) text sometimes instead of the actual images.. any way to omit that?

Comment: may be i could have explained better what happens if i was able to post images... but it wont allow me to since its my very first day here and i only have 3 reputation

Comment: I've updated the answer with alt being updated too so you can compare both sets of code. Welcome btw. Check out the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section to see what type of questions are normally asked, and more importantly get answered on here.

Comment: hey got it working... forgot to add the actual image path... :D my bad... btw if you are kind enough and please explain                   (images.length-1); and 
    if(random < 0) { random = 0 } bit of code to me please? i dont seem to get it through my novice brain..

Comment: I've added a comment to the code explaining the -1. I've removed `if(random < 0)` as it was redundant since `Math.random()` will return a number from 0. It was there in case it returned a negative number.